# Creating menus dynamically in web application

Tags: asp.net

Im creating a web application in asp.net visual studio 2008..
in my application, i have manually created a menu control..
since, the menus changes by needs, i wish to load it dynamically from sql table..
help me with simple application which loads a menu control dynamically and i can develop mine using those concepts....

thank u very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load your menu to a datatable.
then create a repeater in your ascx page (i guess your menur is a user control)
create the template for the repeater.
bind the datatable as the datasource for that repeater.
and there you go. a simple dynamic menu.

dont forget to do a cache on your control. or cache the datatable. so you wont open a connection to the database on every request for a page on your site

here is some examples for using a repeater :

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp
http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/repeater/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Download Source Code Here](http://getcode.in/2012/04/create-dynamic-asp-net-menus-from-database/)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <title>DataBase Driven Menu</title>

</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
 Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" BackColor="#FFFBD6"
 DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em"
 ForeColor="#990000">
 <DataBindings>
 <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" NavigateUrlField="NavigateUrl" TextField="Text"
 ToolTipField="ToolTip" />
 </DataBindings>
 <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
 <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
 <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" />
 <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
 <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
 <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
 <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
 </asp:Menu>

 </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In Code Behind File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 XmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new XmlDataSource();
 xmlDataSource.ID = "xmlDataSource";
 xmlDataSource.EnableCaching = false;

string connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\Admin\WebSite28\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
 {
 string sql = "Select ID, Text,NavigateUrl,ParentID from Menu";
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
 da.Fill(ds);
 da.Dispose();
 }

&nbsp;

ds.DataSetName = "Menus";
 ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Menu";
 DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ParentChild",
 ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["ID"],
 ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["ParentID"],
 true);

relation.Nested = true;
 ds.Relations.Add(relation);

xmlDataSource.Data = ds.GetXml();

//Reformat the xmldatasource from the dataset to fit menu into xml format
 xmlDataSource.TransformFile = Server.MapPath("~/TransformXSLT.xsl");

//assigning the path to start read all MenuItem under MenuItems
 xmlDataSource.XPath = "MenuItems/MenuItem";

//Finally, bind the source to the Menu1 control
 Menu1.DataSource = xmlDataSource;
 Menu1.DataBind();
 }

}
}
```

Create an TransformXSLT.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <!-- Find the root node called Menus
 and call MenuListing for its children -->
 <xsl:template match="/Menus">
 <MenuItems>
 <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
 </MenuItems>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- Allow for recusive child node processing -->
 <xsl:template name="MenuListing">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Menu">
 <MenuItem>
 <!-- Convert Menu child elements to MenuItem attributes -->
 <xsl:attribute name="Text">
 <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="ToolTip">
 <xsl:value-of select="ToolTip"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="NavigateUrl">
 <xsl:value-of select="NavigateUrl"/>
 </xsl:attribute>

 <!-- Call MenuListing if there are child Menu nodes -->
 <xsl:if test="count(Menu) > 0">
 <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
 </xsl:if>
 </MenuItem>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Create Sql Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Text] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [ToolTip] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [NavigateUrl] [varchar](150) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [ParentID] [int] NULL)
```