# How to show sub-menus in Menu control in ASP NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am learning and using VS 2005 to design a website. I used the Menu control to create a menu with some items and some sub-items, for instance:
Home
Product
  Phone
  Cars
News

However, when I run the web page and hover the mouse over the Product menu, its sub-menus did not show up.

Did I miss something? Do I have to do anything else?

Thanks a lot?

Comment: check out this Stack Question

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623818/creating-menus-dynamically-in-web-application/10225825][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623818/creating-menus-dynamically-in-web-application/10225825

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a good tutorial / overview for the menu control. The section that covers Static / Dynamic Display may be pertinent to your question.